# Use conditional inside of another conditional react

Tags: reactjs

I'm attemptiong to use a conditional inside of a "parent" conditional like so:

```js
const linkStyle = {
    
    boxShadow: selectedTheme ? `${boxShadowConcatenated + {selectedTheme.button.buttonBoxShadow ? selectedTheme.button.buttonBoxShadow : "black" }}` : undefined,
    
  };
```

However, the `selectedTheme.button.` is underlined in red.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [**Optional Chaning**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)?

for example, like below.

```js
const linkStyle = {
  boxShadow: selectedTheme ? `${boxShadowConcatenated + selectedTheme.button?.buttonBoxShadow || "black"}` : undefined,
};
```

Comment: @RogerStaxx `selectedTheme.button?.buttonBoxShadow` is actually do like `selectedTheme.button && selectedTheme.button.buttonBoxShadow`. but much shorter than.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getLinkStyle = (selectedTheme) => {
  const boxShadowConcatenated = '5px 10px';
  
  return {
    boxShadow: selectedTheme && `${boxShadowConcatenated} ${selectedTheme.button?.buttonBoxShadow ||  "black"}`
  }
};
  
console.log(getLinkStyle({ button: { buttonBoxShadow: 'red' } }));
console.log(getLinkStyle({ button: {} }));
console.log(getLinkStyle());
```